# Executar próximo áudio em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com uma dúvida de como listar o próximo áudio utilizando javascript, ou seja finalizando uma música já será listado a próxima. atualmente tenho o seguinte código:

```
function loadPlayer() {
    var audioPlayer = new Audio();
    audioPlayer.controls="controls";
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
    document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
    nextSong();
}
function nextSong() {
    if(urls[next]!=undefined) {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
            audioPlayer.src=urls[next];
            audioPlayer.load();
            audioPlayer.play();
            next++;
        } else {
            loadPlayer();
        }
    } else {
        alert('the end!');
    }
}
function errorFallback() {
        nextSong();
}
function playPause() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
        if (audioPlayer.paused) {
            audioPlayer.play();
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
        }
    } else {
        loadPlayer();
    }
}
function pickSong(num) {
    next = num;
    nextSong();
}

var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[1] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[2] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[3] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[4] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[5] = 'audio.mp3';   
    urls[6] = 'audio.mp3';       
var next = 0;
```

Comment: Esse código dá algum erro? Olhando por alto, parece ok.

Comment: seja um pouco mais específico

Comment: @bfavaretto sim o código está ok, a questão é que gostaria de listar o próximo áudio, por exemplo ao finalizar uma música de modo automático iria prosseguir para o segundo... é nesta parte onde está a minha dúvida.

Comment: O arquivo da música que está tocando está em `urls[next]`. Se você quer exibir o nome desse arquivo em algum lugar, é só usar isso. Pelo que entendi do código, a passagem automática para a próxima música já está funcionando.

Comment: Bem, ainda não está funcionando, aqui está o código completo: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/kfGAm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja, dei uma limpada no seu código, e agora funciona sem problemas: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EAqeF

O principal problema era a desnecessária redefinição da variável audioPlayer (`var audioPlayer = ...`) em vários lugares diferentes, de maneira confusa.

O JavaScript ficou desse jeito:

```
var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

var current = 0;

var urls = new Array();

urls[0] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[1] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[2] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[3] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[4] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[5] = 'audio.mp3';
urls[6] = 'audio.mp3';

function playSong() {
  audioPlayer.src = urls[current];
  audioPlayer.load();
  audioPlayer.play();
}

function pickSong(num) {
  current = num;
  playSong();
}

function nextSong() {
  current++;
  if (current >= urls.length) {
    current = 0;
  }
  playSong();
}

audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', nextSong, false);
audioPlayer.addEventListener('error', nextSong, true);
```

Comment: Com certeza, o código ainda pode ser muito melhorado. Apenas dei uma limpada e tornei funcional.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo @J.Bruni o código ficou bastante bonito de ver. ;)